# WireMock affects other tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, wiremock

All existing tests are annotated with

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles({"test"})
```

I have added

spring-cloud-contract-wiremock

to my project and created a test with the following annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 10000, stubs = {"classpath:stubs/mappings"})
@ActiveProfiles({"test"})
```

When I run all the tests together, then all the tests followed after that WireMock test are starting to fail.

Issues are like:

```
Caught exception while invoking 'beforeTestMethod' callback on TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@42f3156d] for test method [public void com.example.MyClass.foo1()] and test instance [com.example.MyClassTest@5e3569e8]
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource...
```

These failing methods are annotated with:

```
@Test
@SqlGroup
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are you sure it is WireMock causing the issue?

Comment: @Oozeerally when I remove the entire class, everything is working

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I have

```
ddl-auto: create-drop
```

in my config, but it should be

```
ddl-auto: create-only
```